# IIS CGI could not locate my python modules

Tags: python, iis, cgi

I am trying to run my python scripts on my IIS website using CGI and I am having trouble with importing. When run on its own, the python scripts finds the `mysql.connector` module installed in my os perfectly fine, but when I try to run it on the website, it gives a Bad Gateway (502.2) error with the stacktrace stating `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'`. I'm assuming CGI cannot find the module in my OS, how can I let it find the module? Do I have to specify my modules folder somewhere in the IIS like a PATH variable?

Here is the complete stacktrace of the bad gateway page:
**The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documents\adet\ind.py", line 2, in  import python_mysql File "C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documents\adet\python_mysql.py", line 1, in  import mysql.connector ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector' ".**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please format your answers using the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I simply copied and pasted all of my modules in my modules folder to my website's folder. I guessed that since my personal imports were working that it should also work if I added the other modules to the same folder and lo, it did. I hope there's a cleaner way to solve this, but for now I'll choose this as a solution.